# How to toggle AutoShowToolbarInFullScreen via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I need help with hiding/showing the toolbar in Safari by using the terminal.

I already found out that there exists a key within ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist called `AutoShowToolbarInFullScreen` that is either `false` or `true` and it changes when clicking *"Always show toolbar in fullscreen mode"* (*Safari->View->Always show toolbar in fullscreen mode*).

I tried setting the property using defaults:

`defaults write com.apple.Safari AutoShowToolbarInFullScreen -bool true` (or false)

That worked, however, the UI did not update or layout itself after setting the property.

Is there any way how to hide/show the toolbar in Safari or to update the Safari UI via the Terminal?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.